# using asp classic to interface with phoneburner

Tags: asp-classic

i have a curl example:

> $ curl https://www.phoneburner.com/rest/1/tranquility

```
{
    "http_status": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "tranquility": 
    {
    "tranquility": 
    [

        {
            "meaning": "the quality or state of being tranquil; calm."
        }
    ],
    "total_results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "page_size": 1,
    "total_pages": 1
}
}
```

i need to use asp classic to send this request to phoneburner

then i need to send:

> $ curl https://www.phoneburner.com/rest/1/members/ \
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer EibGl9i8WNi0iI3a0He6PYg1Kntpzq8y3foSxQyg"

```
{
        "http_status": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "members":
        {
                "total_results": 1,
                "members":
                [

                    {
                            "user_id": "1234567",
                            "username": "saulgoodman",
                            "first_name": "Saul",
                            "last_name": "Goodman",
                            "email_address": "callsaul@bettercallsaul.com",
                            "date_added": "2013-01-17 17:12:13",
                            "phone": "9492181234",
                            "display_name": "Standard Account",
                            "billing_item_id": "131",
                            "subscription_status": "1",
                            "_link":
                            {
                                    "self":
                                    {
                                            "href": "\/rest\/1\/members\/1234567"
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            ],
            "page": 1,
            "page_size": 1,
            "total_pages": 1
    }
```

how do i send these with asp classic?

Answer (score 2):

The goal you're trying to get to is to send an HTTP POST with custom post data and a custom header, all via an ASP script.

ASP Classic has two different implementations: VBScript and JScript.  The answer I'm about to provide is VBScript.

```
<%
sub DoPOST(strJsonData, strEndpointURL, strAuthorizationToken)
    dim objHttp
    set objHttp = server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    with objHttp
        .open "POST", strEndpointURL, false
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        if len(strAuthorizationToken) > 0 then
            .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer "& strAuthorizationToken
        end if
        .send strJsonData
    end with
    Set xmlhttp = nothing
end sub

strPostData = "{""http_status"": 200, ""status"": ""success"", ""tranquility"": { ""tranquility"": [{""meaning"": ""the quality or state of being tranquil; calm.""}],""total_results"": 1,""page"": 1,""page_size"": 1,""total_pages"": 1}}"
call DoPOST(strPostData, "https://www.phoneburner.com/rest/1/tranquility", empty)


strPostData = "{ ""http_status"": 200, ""status"": ""success"", ""members"": { ""total_results"": 1, ""members"": [{""user_id"": ""1234567"",""username"": ""saulgoodman"",""first_name"": ""Saul"",""last_name"": ""Goodman"",""email_address"": ""callsaul@bettercallsaul.com"",""date_added"": ""2013-01-17 17:12:13"",""phone"": ""9492181234"",""display_name"": ""Standard Account"",""billing_item_id"": ""131"",""subscription_status"": ""1"",""_link"":{""self"":{""href"": ""\/rest\/1\/members\/1234567""}}}],""page"": 1,""page_size"": 1,""total_pages"": 1}"
call DoPOST(strPostData, "https://www.phoneburner.com/rest/1/members/", "EibGl9i8WNi0iI3a0He6PYg1Kntpzq8y3foSxQyg")
%>
```

Explanation:

I've built a subroutine that performs the HTTP POST operation via the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object.  You can call this subroutine twice, simply providing it different parameters each time.

Some important points about the code I've provided:

1) You have to escape each quotation in your JSON string because ASP VBScript only uses quotation strings to set off string literals, so by doubling the quotation marks in your JSON with another, you effectively escape it (e.g. "JSON" becomes ""JSON"").

2) The second parameter is the URL you need to send the data to.

3) The third parameter is your authorization token to be passed in an HTTP header in the second POST (i.e. Authorization: Bearer EibGl9i8WNi0iI3a0He6PYg1Kntpzq8y3foSxQyg).  If you provide it in the argument list, the subroutine will send it in the HTTP POST with the Authorization header; if you leave it blank (i.e. empty), the header will be left out.  This is an important distinction between the first call and the second call to the subroutine.

Comment: OK, That seems to have worked(No errors returned) . How do i get the feed back from the call? The Results?

Comment: ok added: Response.write objHttp.responseText and i got:{ "http_status": 503, "status": "failure", "debug_codes": [ { "code": 50300, "reason": "The HTTP verb used is not supported for the resource" } ] }  { "http_status": 401, "status": "error", "debug_codes": [ { "code": 40108, "reason": "Invalid oauth token" } ] }  maybe this is correct??

Comment: To correct the 50300 failure, you need to use whatever HTTP verb the API is expecting, e.g. GET, PUT, DELETE.  It is odd that it doesn't want a POST.

Comment: I now a "Real" statement:strPostData =""...................................................
Call DoPOST(strPostData,"https://www.phoneburner.com/rest/1/folders","uwC7Lz1hAe88w2QVoM3Qkney1h5ifW7drjJVmWb0")  this returns                  ....>>>>>{ "http_status": 400, "status": "error", "debug_codes": [ { "code": 40004, "reason": "A required field is not set" } ] }